# React 16 and Babel 6 from the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser

I'd like to use React from the browser without creating bundles with browserify/webpack.

I'm trying to use [babel-standalone](https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone) and react from the browser, I have modified some code I had but I get **ReactDOM is not defined** plus other two warnings (process is not defined)

I've found the reference to react and react dom [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/react-dom). Is it correct to include the cjs version? What does cjs stand for?

The code I'm using is the following. I'd like to use ReactDOM.render

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/cjs/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/cjs/react-dom.development.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>

<div id="output"></div>
<script type="text/babel">

ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello World</h1>,
    document.querySelector('output')
);

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry about not originally answering your cjs question. I believe it's referring to CommonJS. Since you're just using a simple HTML template, you can use the plain old JavaScript bundles instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe cjs is referring to CommonJS. Since you're using a simple HTML template, you can include the plain JavaScript bundles instead.

I changed the included script tags according to this [minimal HTML template](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/master/static/html/single-file-example.html) from the official React documentation.

I also changed `document.querySelector('output')` to `document.getElementById('output')`.

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello World</h1>,
        document.getElementById('output')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between cloudflare and unpkg.com?

Comment: They're both CDNs. I looked at cloudflare and I couldn't find a JavaScript bundle that wasn't CJS or UMD. The official React documentation uses unpkg.com so I kept it the same.